# How to parse json object to update HANA table?

Tags: javascript, json, api, hana

I have a HANA table with 2 columns and I am trying to update one column for instance. I am really new to jSON/HANA and I am trying to parse a json array by using a SQL query to loop through the json object and update my table with the updated values.

```
function updateData(){
     var param1 = $.request.parameters.get('param1');
     var param2 = $.request.parameters.get('param2');
     var conn = $.db.getConnection();
     var pstmt;
     var rs;

     var data = getJSON("URL");
       var arr = [data];
        arr.forEach(function(d)){
            if (param1 !=null){
             console.log(d.param2);
            }
         });

         query = 'UPDATE schema.tableName SET param1=? WHERE param2=?';
         pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
         pstmt.setString(1, param1);
         pstmt.setString(2, param2);
         rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
         conn.commit();
         rs.close();
         pstmt.close();
         conn.close();
}
```

The result should include the updated new values of param2 in the table but it's not working.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

On HANA database you can use "**JSON_TABLE**" to parse JSON data into a table.
After you have your data in a tabular way, you can use it inserteing or updating a database table